# Derivation of Allen-Uzawa Elasticity of Substitution from Hicks Elasticity of Substitution in two goods

Tags: microeconomics, elasticity, cost-functions

Everywhere I've looked, the author of the text asserts that the Allen-Uzawa Elasticity of Substitution is equal to the Hicks Elasticity of Substitution in two goods. I've spent a long time trying to show this is true, and it does not seem trivial at all to me.

I was given the definition of Hicks Elasticity of Substitution in goods $x,y$ as follows:

$$\sigma=\frac{d\log\frac{y}{x}}{d\log\frac{U_x}{U_y}}
$$

And this derivation I understood, as coming from the total differential of the elasticity definition. Using [this paper](https://www.revistasober.org/article/5de93d7f0e8825317be31d41/pdf/resr-38-1-119.pdf), I was able to derive the following elasticity of substitution identity:

$$\sigma=\frac{U_xU_y(xU_x+yU_y)}{xy(Ux^2U_{yy}-2U_xU_yU_{xy}+U_y^2U_{xx})}
$$

However I was also given the Allen-Uzawa Elasticity of substitution. Given $e(p_x,p_y,\overline{U})$ as the expenditure function

$$\sigma=\frac{e_{p_y,p_x}e}{e_{p_x}e_{p_y}}
$$

Using the Lagrangian I was able to recognize the numerator of the Hicks ES identity as being equal to the following, with $\eta$ being the Lagrange multiplier of the expenditure minimization problem:

$$U_xU_y(xU_x+yU_y)=\frac{U_xU_y}{\eta}(xp_x+yp_y)=\left(\frac{U_xU_y}{\eta}\right)e
$$

And using Shepard's lemma,

$$xy=e_{p_x}e_{p_y}
$$

So given these identities, I derived that

$$e_{p_x,p_y}=\frac{1}{\eta\left(\frac{U_x}{U_y}U_{yy}-2U_{xy}+\frac{U_y}{U_x}U_{xx}\right)}
$$

Then applying Euler's theorem to $U_x$ and $U_y$ I got

$$U_x=xU_{xx}+yU_{xy}
$$
$$U_y=yU_{yy}+xU_{xy}
$$

Solving these for the second partials, plugging them in, and a lot of simplification, I got

$$\frac{1}{\eta\left(\frac{U_x}{y}+\frac{U_y}{x}-\frac{U_{xy}}{xyU_xU_y}(xU_x+yU_y)^2\right)}
$$

Which, using the Lagrangian, first order conditions $p_x=\eta U_x$ and $p_x=\eta U_y$ and the definition of the expenditure function, I got

$$\frac{1}{\eta\left(\frac{e_{p_x}p_x+e_{p_y}p_y}{\eta e_{p_y}e_{p_x}}-\frac{U_{xy}e^2}{e_{p_x}e_{p_y} p_x p_y}\right)}
$$

Which after applying Euler's Theorem again and simplifying further, I got

$$\frac{e_{p_x}e_{p_y}p_xp_y}{ep_xp_y-U_{xy}e^2\eta}=e_{p_x,p_y}
$$

And after this, I see no fruitful way to continue.

No matter how hard I try, I am unable to reconcile these two definitions.

Any and all help would be appreciated

Comment: This is an interesting question. Its only true when there are two goods. Im not sure exactly, but at some point that must be invoked. Also, $e_{x,y}$ is equal to the cross price elasticity of demand $\frac{\partial y}{\partial p_x}$.